# Can't get LinqDataSource to recognize deatil relations

Tags: c#, asp.net, linqdatasource

what I have are two tables, Publication and DTPersonnel.  Publication has a primary Key and the other (DTPersonnel) has a field that is  link back Publication. I sent up a DBML layout  for my LinqDataSource and link the two tables..
I have added the LinqDataSource component to my web page and (for testing) a label.

I then set up the label data-binding to point to a field in DTPersonnel.DTRoleID like this:

```
 <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
        DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
    Text='<%# BIND("DTPersonnels.DTRoleID") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:FormView>
    </asp:Content>
```

My LinqDataSource is setup like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Layout.aspx.cs" Inherits="AequorPubTracker.Account.Layout" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ContextTypeName="AequorPubTracker.LayoutDataContext" EntityTypeName="" 
        onselecting="LinqDataSource1_Selecting" TableName="Publications" 

        Select="new (DTPersonnels.DTRoleID,PublicationID, DTPersonnels, ActLAYDate, ActRRIPDate, ActPPIDate, ActPPODate, ActECTWDate, TargetECTWDate, TargetPPIDate, TargetRRIPDate, TargetPPODate, TargetLAYDate)">
    </asp:LinqDataSource>
```

But when I run the app in the browser I get the following error:

> Exception Details: System.Web.Query.Dynamic.ParseException: No
>   property or field 'DTRoleID' exists in type 'EntitySet`1'

I hope I gave enough information any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume since you are specifying the select clause, this is a read-only view of the data. If that is so, your problem has a fairly straightforward solution. However, if it is not so (of which I am uncertain since that your code calls the `Bind` method rather than `Eval`), there is more complex handling required to update related fields as a `LinqDataSource` with the `Select` member specified cannot allow updating.

Ensure you select the `DTPersonnels` member in your clause, but remove `DTPersonnels.DTRoleID` from the selection. If you call `Eval("DTPersonnels.DTRoleID")` it will display the related record's member value.

I presume, however, there is also a problem in the configuration of your schema file. From what I can infer, you expect there to be a 1-to-1 relationship between `Publications` and `DTPersonnel`. However, since the error indicates that there is no member on `EntitySet`, that implies that you have allowed a 1-to-many relationship where `Publications` have many `DTPersonnel`. If there is not a 1-to-1 relationship, your code will not be able to determine which related record's `DTRoleID` to display.

If you actually **DO** intend for there to be many `DTPersonnel` related to a `Publication`, then you may want to approach this from the other way around of displaying a list of `DTPersonnel` and showing their related `Publication`'s data instead.

Comment: Yes, I had to DTPersonnel because I have many DTPersonnel data-rows I also used the eval instead of binding it that seem to solve my problem thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you're wondering where the error itself is coming from, it's located here:

```
Select="new (DTPersonnels.DTRoleID,PublicationID, DTPersonnels, ActLAYDate, ActRRIPDate, ActPPIDate, ActPPODate, ActECTWDate, TargetECTWDate, TargetPPIDate, TargetRRIPDate, TargetPPODate, TargetLAYDate)">
```

Since you are selecting data from the Publications table, it is looking for a field "DTRoleID" there. I'm guessing that table does not have a "DTRoleID" field, causing the error you are receiving.